# Queue does not showing in Rabbitmq

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have two separate services one called Teacher.API and Process.API. Teacher service generates POST requests and there Teacher details will send into the Process Service, according to my need.

This is how I configure MassTrasit in both services.

in the **Teacher.API**

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
    {
        config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
    });
});
```

and in the **Process.API.**

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<TeacherConsumer>();
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("teacherQueue", ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
            ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
            ep.ConfigureConsumer<TeacherConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});
```

And in the Teacher Controller, my POST request as follows,

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Registraion(Teacher Teacher)
{
    if (Teacher != null)
    {
        Teacher.BookedOn = DateTime.Now;
        Uri uri = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/teacherQueue");
        var endPoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(uri);
        await endPoint.Send(Teacher);
        return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

here I'm creating a new `teacherQueue` queue and push the Teacher object.

My problem is, RabbitMQ management plugin, does not show `teacherQueue` in the queue section but showing it in the Exchanges.

[image]

[image]

My consumer part is as follows, this consumer is also not hit.

```
public class TeacherConsumer : IConsumer<Teacher>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Teacher> context)
    {
        var data = context.Message;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Any reason? what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the AspNetCore package, and the call to:

```cs
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Which actually starts the bus.

Comment: Yup, that's the reason. Thank you for saving my time.

Comment: you bit changed my code, may I know the reason?

Comment: Your configuration was outdated, based on an earlier version of MassTransit.

Comment: okay got it. :) I think it's better to follow the MassTransit doc? is it?

Comment: That's exactly [what is in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/#edit-program-cs-2).

Comment: Thanks for everything @Chris Patterson